# Shell script too many arguments error [unable to resolve with using quotes]

Tags: shell

I am getting input from the user via command line and want to check if there is an input or not using the $@

the user invokes such as the following ways:

```
sh program <file1> <file2> ..
```

or

```
sh program < file1
```

in the script i am doing the following:

```
test -z "$@"  
if test $? -eq 0
then
    compute
else
       do something..
fi
```

if the user invokes the program with a multiple lines, then i get an error from
test -z "$@" saying that "test: too many arguments"

i tried to resolve this, but i am stuck. do you know how i can overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that given something like:

```
test -z "$@"
```

If the user runs your script with multiple arguments, this ends up being equivalent to:

```
test -z "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
```

And that's why you're getting the "too many arguments" error.  You should read the "Special Parameters" subsection of the "PARAMETERS" section of the `bash(1)` man page for details.  What you really want check is probably `$#`, the number of arguments passed to your script:

```
if test $# -eq 0
then
    compute
else
       do something..
fi
```

But you can also test against `$*`, which like `$@` expands to the command line arguments but as a single string:

```
if test -z "$*"
then
    compute
else
       do something..
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`$#` gives you the number of arguments.

```
if (($# > 0)); then
    echo "passed $# arguments: $@"
else
    echo "no arguments"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**$?** is the shell exit status variable. If you want to check if the last command entered is executed in a true or false by returning 0 for true and non-zero values for other.

**$#** is the shell variable which show how many arguments does a user passed. And you can access those arguments with variables $0,$1 up to $9, where the $0 variable carries the command name, so you would  be using starting $1.

Example.

```
if test $# -gt 0
then
echo "You pass $# Arguments";
echo "First Argument is : $1";
echo "Second Argument is : $2";
else
echo "You did not pass any Arguments";
fi
```